# Form in Django not saving my article to database

Tags: python, django, database

I am making a blog/articles page in django, and whenever I try to enter some input, it doesn't save to the database. I have tried re-running the server, refreshing, still it doesn't save. I am getting no errors, 200 code meaning it's all OK.

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def new_article(req):
if req.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.CreateArticle(req.POST, req.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        #save article to database
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = req.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('articles:list')
else:
    form = forms.CreateArticle()
return render(req, 'articles/createArticle.html', {'form': form})
```

**createArticle.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Article Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="{% url 'articles:list'%}"><img src="/static/logo.png" alt="TBD"/></a>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <form class="logout-link" action="/accounts/logout/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Log Out</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="create-article">
    <h2>Write your own Article!!</h2>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <form class="newArticleForm" action="/articles/create/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form }}
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default = None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]+'...'
```

I am following Net Ninja Django Tutorial and have been doing the exact same things he is showing. Please help

Comment: Check if your request is going inside the form.is_valid() if condition or not. I think you've errors in your form. Add a print statement and check.

Answer (score 1):

Hello try putting the csrf token inside the creation form:

```
<form class="newArticleForm" action="/articles/create/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, that actually worked, thank you, but can you explain why wasn't it submitting before without giving any errors.

Comment: Do you have debug enabled and are you using the manage.py runserver command ?

Comment: @AnimeshSingh: because the CSRF token was not submitted... it was *outside* the form...